# How to create trigger in phpmyadmin

Tags: triggers, phpmyadmin

I am having this error when I try to create a trigger in phpmyadmin. What am I doing wrong?

SQL query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_social 
AFTER INSERT ON sa_users_social
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO fsb2_users ( u_social_id, u_auth, u_nickname, u_email, u_avatar, u_signature, u_language, u_joined, u_sexe, u_rank_id ) 
VALUES ('NEW.social_id',  '1',  'username',  'email',  'photoURL',  'description',  'fr',  'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',  'gender',  '0');
```

Error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 5

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't like stored procedure, you don't have to put BEGIN...END there. Could you delete BEGIN and try again?

Or, if you need to put BEGIN there, you can do it like this:

```
delimiter #
CREATE TRIGGER ins_social 
AFTER INSERT ON sa_users_social
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO fsb2_users ( u_social_id, u_auth, u_nickname, u_email, u_avatar, u_signature, u_language, u_joined, u_sexe, u_rank_id ) 
    VALUES ('NEW.social_id',  '1',  'username',  'email',  'photoURL',  'description',  'fr',  'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',  'gender',  '0');
END#
delimiter ;
```

Another possible error is that you put single quote around each value, which makes them passed as varchars. In the statement, I guess u_social_id is an numerical type, right? So you pass a varchar value to a numerical type field, that's a problem. Since you didn't post your table structure here. It's just a guess. :)

Comment: Thank you Chong Tang, It seem to be working when I delete BEGIN, but I get this error : #1419 - You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable) . I am trying to figure out how to grant my username "Super privilege", my version of PHPmyadmin do not have a privilege tab where would be able to set it. Yes, u_social_id is a numerical type. Also, with the delimiter # it doesn't work.